# What is the format of .onion pseudo domain addresses?

Tags: onion-services, onion-routing

What is the format of .onion pseudo-top-level domain addresses?

Answer (score 5):

Quoting from Wikipedia:

> Addresses in the .onion pseudo-TLD are opaque, non-mnemonic, 16-character alpha-semi-numeric hashes which are automatically generated based on a public key when a hidden service is configured. These 16-character hashes can be made up of any letter of the alphabet, and decimal digits beginning with 2 and ending with 7, thus representing an 80-bit number in base32.

Answer (score 1):

Onion-addresses can also have another "subdomain" part on the beginning

so you can have

```
whatever.abcdefghij234567.onion
```

As well as

```
abcdefghij234567.onion
```

For SSL technical reasons, the clearnet tor2web proxies don't support these domain names (e.g. tor2web.org )

Comment: Are you sure, to my knowledge the tor spec doesn't currently allow subdomains.